# How to perform a search-replace on an ENV variable and echo the result in a response header (.HTACCESS)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http-headers, httpresponse, canonical-link

I am setting a canonical link response header for all static assets.

This is what I am doing:

Creating an ENV variable and setting the canonical header:

```
<filesMatch ".(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf|webp|woff2|woff|eot|ttf|svg)$">
    RewriteRule .* - [E=FILENAME:https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}]
    Header set Link '<%{FILENAME}e>; rel="canonical"'
</filesMatch>
```

I'd like to search-replace inside the variable and override the variable before setting the header.

Something equivalent in PHP:

```
$NEW_FILENAME = str_replace("lalala", "lololo", $FILENAME);
```

And then set the header with NEW_FILENAME

Any help would be very appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer myself, hope it can help anyone:

```
<filesMatch ".(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf|webp|woff2|woff|eot|ttf|svg)$">
    SetEnvIf Request_URI "^.*lalala/(.*)$" SITE=domain.com/lololo/$1
    Header set Link '<https://%{SITE}e>; rel="canonical"'
</filesMatch>
```

Regards!